# Can one Virtual service fan out the request to multiple services

Tags: istio

You will have request for (say /test ) , and that request has to be redirected to multiple services 
kind of multitasking behavior

I tried below things , but it didn't work 
- route:
   - destination:
       host: details
       subset: v1
   - destination: 
       host: preview
       subset: v1

I have code for matching the test prefix and added only that part where actual redirection is happening.

In simpler way . I want to know , how to achieve fan out in istio

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared a full `VirtualService` manifest, however in the similar scenario I used the following configuration in order to distinguish HTTP requests to the same prefix path by applying specific custom headers:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: reviews
spec:
  hosts:
    - example
  gateways:
    - example-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        test:
          exact: details
    - uri:
        prefix: /test
    route:
    - destination:
        host: details
        subset: v1
  - match:
    - headers:
        test:
          exact: preview
    - uri:
       prefix: /test
    route:
    - destination:
        host: preview
        subset: v1
```

Of course don't forget to accomplish appropriate `DestinationRule's`

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: details
spec:
  host: details
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: preview
spec:
  host: preview
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
```

You can find more relevant information in the official Istio traffic management [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/).

Comment: Thanks mk_sta . But my scenario is little different. I will get one request from outside  & that request will be fan out to multiple services .

Comment: Actually, you have to specify the matching criteria for traffic routing, and each routing rule has to be unique, that's why I used custom headers in order to split network traffic within a same URI path. Furthermore, `VirtualService` should be defined one per each host.

Comment: I have used NAT streaming to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mirror option in Istio https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/mirroring/